# Mockito: Wanted but not invoked - however, there were other interactions

Tags: java, groovy, mockito

I'm receiving this error and have researched that it is because I am not calling the Mocked class but the actual class? I've looked over it numerous times and it seems to be pretty straightforward to simply be invoking the mock. The main error I get is

**Wanted but not invoked:**

**dsIn.setItemString(1, "MAKE", "MAKE");**

**However, there were other interactions with this mock:**

**dsIn.getItemNumber(1, "APPROVED");**

**dsIn.setItemString(1, "VIN", "VIN");**

**dsIn.setItemObject(1, "MAKE", null);**

And then it just continues through the others.

Below is the class to be tested:

```
if(dsIn.getItemNumber(1,"APPROVED") == 1) {
  throw new TRDIException("Cannot change Approved record");
}

String sql;

sql = "select c.EQUIPMENT_NAME, c.VIN, c.MAKE, c.MODEL,c.EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID,c.SALVAGE_VALUE,c.GARAGE_ASSIGNED,c.EQ_LOCATION_ID, c.DEPT_PM_NOTIFY, " +
"GET_DEPR_VALUE(c.EQUIPMENT_ID) AS EQ_CURRENT_VALUE " +
" from EQUIPMENT_INVENTORY c where c.EQUIPMENT_ID =  " +  newValueIn ;

DataStore ds = dl.createDataStore(sql);
ds.retrieve();
dsIn.setItemString(1,"VIN",ds.getItemString(1,"VIN"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"MAKE",ds.getItemObject(1,"MAKE"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"MODEL",ds.getItemObject(1,"MODEL"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID",ds.getItemObject(1,"EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"GARAGE_ASSIGNED",ds.getItemObject(1,"GARAGE_ASSIGNED"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"EQ_LOCATION_ID",ds.getItemObject(1,"EQ_LOCATION_ID"));
dsIn.setItemObject(1,"SALVAGE_VALUE",ds.getItemObject(1,"SALVAGE_VALUE"));

if(dsIn.getItemNumber(1,"APPROVED") == 1) {
  throw new TRDIException("Cannot change approved record");
}
```

Below is the test class:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestFillEqDisposalAttr extends TestGroovy {

@Mock
private DataLayer dl;
@Mock
private DataStore dsIn;
@Mock
private DataStore ds;

private String newValueIn;

@Parameter
public String client;

@Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
public static Object[] data() {
    return new Object[]{
            "test"
    };
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    //groovy script file to test
    groovyScriptFile = new File(GROOVY_SCRIPTS_FOLDER + "/" + client + "/test.groovy");

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    Mockito.when(dl.createDataStore(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(ds);
    newValueIn = "1";

    //groovy script parameters
    addGroovyBindingVariable(GroovyScriptArgName.DATALAYER, dl);
    addGroovyBindingVariable(GroovyScriptArgName.DATASTORE, dsIn);
    addGroovyBindingVariable(GroovyScriptArgName.NEW_VALUE, newValueIn);
}

/**
 */
@Test
public void testEqDisposalAttr() throws IOException, TRDIException {
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "VIN")).thenReturn("VIN");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "MAKE")).thenReturn("MAKE");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "MODEL")).thenReturn("MODEL");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID")).thenReturn("EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "GARAGE_ASSIGNED")).thenReturn("GARAGE_ASSIGNED");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "EQ_LOCATION_ID")).thenReturn("EQ_LOCATION_ID");
    Mockito.when(ds.getItemString(1, "SALVAGE_VALUE")).thenReturn("SALVAGE_VALUE");

    evaluate();

    String sql = "select c.EQUIPMENT_NAME, c.VIN, c.MAKE, c.MODEL,c.EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID,c.SALVAGE_VALUE,c.GARAGE_ASSIGNED,c.EQ_LOCATION_ID, c.DEPT_PM_NOTIFY, " +
            "GET_DEPR_VALUE(c.EQUIPMENT_ID) AS EQ_CURRENT_VALUE " +
            " from EQUIPMENT_INVENTORY c where c.EQUIPMENT_ID =  " + newValueIn ;

    Mockito.verify(dl).createDataStore(sql);
    Mockito.verify(ds).retrieve();

    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "VIN", "VIN");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "MAKE", "MAKE");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "MODEL", "MODEL");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID", "EQUIPMENT_CLASS_CODE_ID");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "GARAGE_ASSIGNED", "GARAGE_ASSIGNED");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "EQ_LOCATION_ID", "EQ_LOCATION_ID");
    Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemString(1, "SALVAGE_VALUE", "SALVAGE_VALUE");
}
```

Comment: Wanted `dsIn.setItemString(...)`, but the code does `dsIn.setItemObject(...);`.

Comment: Ah yes. I see that in the stack now: dsIn.setItemObject(1, "MAKE", null);
 I still don't understand why this is happening though